# ACTIVE RECORD REGULAR EXPRESSION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord

I need to know how use regular expression with active record. 
I need to create a custom validation where the phone can not have less than 10 digits without counting non-numeric characters.
Thank you so much for your help!.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+use+regular+expression+with+active+record

Answer (score 3):

You can validate the phone format in your model, and in the with option to pass the regex:

```
validates :phone, format: { with: /\d{10,}/ }
```

In this case the phone must have ten or more digits. Note are ten digits one after another.

Comment: Thanks Sebastián! =)